# Kusto: Copy rows from one table and Append to the other within the same cluster

Tags: database, azure-data-explorer

In Kusto, is there any way to copy rows from one table and **append** to the other within the same cluster?

For example, I want to only copy the rows with student data with gender of `female` to the other table.

```
Student
| where gender has 'female'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.set-or-append OtherTable <| Student
| where gender has 'female'

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `.set-or-append` command, that ingests the results of a query into your table of choice.

See: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query)

if you want to do this at the time of ingestion into the source table, you can use [an update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/update-policy).